# Jump to the start of a Bash script

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to jump to the start of a Bash script. Is there an easy way to do this?

```
#start
echo "Start"

read -p "Input: " i

if [ i = j ]
then
z=1

elif [ i = n ]
then
#jump to start

elif [ i = x ]
then
exit
fi
```

Comment: Have you tried using a loop?

Comment: @MarcJefferson5 : I hope you know that the conditions in your `if` statements are all meaningless, an that you wanted to show only the general structure of your program without revealing unrelevant details, but to aswer your question: There are, fortunately, no `goto` statements neither in bash nor in (POSIX) shell. You **can** call your program recursively, which is similar in effect, but not exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
#start
while true; do
  echo "Start"

  read -p "Input: " i

  if [ $i = $j ]
  then
    z=1
    break
  elif [ $i = $n ]
  then
    continue #jump to start 
  elif [ $i = $x ]
  then
    exit
  fi
done
#you will arrive here when i = j
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't really make up the purpose of the code given, but I think that something like this gives you an understanding of whats happening:

```
inputvar=""

while [[ "$inputvar" != "x" ]] 
do

    #start
    echo "Start"

    read -p "Input: " inputvar

    if [ "$inputvar" = "j" ]
    then
        echo "input equals j"

    elif [ "$inputvar" = "n" ]
    then
        echo "input equals n"
    fi

done
echo "input equals x"
```